# How do I get user data from Okta after authentication? How do I capture the authorization code and use tokens to extract info?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, okta-api, okta-auth-js

I have used console.log at different locations in my function. My current code signs me in and redirects me to the same page. And I don't see any of the console.logs from the UseEffect() or HandleRedirect function. I don't get why the useeffect() or HandleRedirect is not being triggered after the authentication is completed.

Am I using the wrong redirect? Since I am using expo I just have my expo scheme as the name of the project. How would it be different if it was just firebase?

```
const AuthComponent = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null); // State to hold the response
  console.log("Entering auth component")

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRedirect = async (event) => {
      console.log("Handling redirect with URL:", event.url);
      let data = Linking.parse(event.url);
      console.log("Parsed redirect data:", data);

      // Extract the authorization code from the URL
      if (data.queryParams && data.queryParams.code) {
        const code = data.queryParams.code;
        console.log("Authorization code received:", code); // Log the authorization code

        // Now you can exchange the authorization code for an access token
        const accessToken = await exchangeCodeForToken(code);
        if (accessToken) {
          // With the access token, fetch the user's information from Okta
          const userInfo = await getUserInfoFromOkta(accessToken);
          if (userInfo) {
            // Create or update the user document in Firestore with the fetched user info
            await createUserDocument(userInfo);
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Authorization code not found in the URL");
      }
    };

    // Subscribe to the redirect event
    const subscription = Linking.addEventListener('url', handleRedirect);

    // Cleanup
    return () => {
      console.log("Removing URL event listener...");
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  const signInWithOkta = async () => {
    console.log("Initiating sign-in with Okta...");
    let authUrl = buildAuthUrl();
    console.log("Auth URL:", authUrl);
    const result = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(
      authUrl,
      oktaConfig.redirectUri
    );
    console.log("Auth session result:", result);
    setResponse(result); // Store the response in state
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Button title="Sign in with Okta" onPress={signInWithOkta} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

The code should sign in me with okta, and extract user information based on the sign-ins.